# simple java frame with multiple controls

Tags: java

i want to create a form using simple Frame class, but every time i run the program only last added component is visible. i want all form elements to be visible. And i dont want to use Jframe.

code -

```
import java.awt.*;

class Form
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {               
            Frame p = new Frame();  
            p.setVisible(true);
            p.setSize(200,200);

            Label l1 = new Label("Enter your name");
            TextField t1 = new TextField("Name",10);

            Label l2 = new Label("Enter your Address");
            TextArea ta1 = new TextArea("Address",10,20);

            Label l3 = new Label("Enter your email");
            TextField t3 = new TextField("Name",10);

            CheckboxGroup cg = new CheckboxGroup();
            Checkbox c1 = new Checkbox("Kahibi tak na bho",cg,false);
            Checkbox c2 = new Checkbox("Badhir",cg,false);

            Button b1 = new Button("Submit");
            Button b2 = new Button("Reset");

            p.add(l1);  
            p.add(t1);
            p.add(l2);
            p.add(ta1);
            p.add(l3);
            p.add(t3);
            p.add(c1);
            p.add(c2);
            p.add(b1);
            p.add(b2);

    }
}
```

output -

[image]

Thank you for helping....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a layout to your frame, e.g if you want to display all the elements *horizontally* one after another, you'd want to set the layout to `BasicHorizontalLayoutManager`

```
Frame p = new Frame(); 
p.setLayout(new BasicHorizontalLayoutManager());
```

Go through different layout implementations here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html